# How to re-raise an exception in nested try/except blocks?

Tags: python, exception, nested, raise

I know that if I want to re-raise an exception, I simple use `raise` without arguments in the respective `except` block. But given a nested expression like

```
try:
    something()
except SomeError as e:
    try:
        plan_B()
    except AlsoFailsError:
        raise e  # I'd like to raise the SomeError as if plan_B()
                 # didn't raise the AlsoFailsError
```

how can I re-raise the `SomeError` without breaking the stack trace? `raise` alone would in this case re-raise the more recent `AlsoFailsError`. Or how could I refactor my code to avoid this issue?

Comment: Have you tried putting `plan_B` in another function that returns `True` on success, and `False` on exception? Then the outer `except` block could just be `if not try_plan_B(): raise`

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Unfortunately the more realistic case is that this is inside a function accepting arbitrary objects `arg` and I'd try calling `arg.plan_B()` which might raise an `AttributeError` due to `arg` not providing a plan B

Comment: Have a look at the traceback module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples

Comment: @Paco Thanks, I will (Though [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18188660/321973) already shows a simpler way)

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I wrote up [an answer based on your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18189174/321973), which looks less pythonic than [user4815162342's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18188660/321973) though. But that's due to my wanting to also have a return value and allowing `plan_B` to raise exceptions

Comment: I'm confused by the code example.  There is no `raise` w/o arguments. The code correcly reraises 1st exception. The comment is misleading: why reraise is in `except AlsoFailsError` block if the comment tells "as if plan_B() **didn't** raise the AlsoFailsError".

Comment: @JCode Honestly I don't remember my exact thought from five years ago, the example looks exactly like the accepted answer's Python3 code... But as [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188563/how-to-re-raise-an-exception-in-nested-try-except-blocks?noredirect=1#comment71264711_18189174) I'd probably use `raise from` now anyway

Answer (score 225, accepted):

As of Python 3, the traceback is stored in the exception, so a simple `raise e` will do the (mostly) right thing:

```
try:
    something()
except SomeError as e:
    try:
        plan_B()
    except AlsoFailsError:
        raise e  # or raise e from None - see below
```

The traceback produced will include an additional notice that `SomeError` occurred while handling `AlsoFailsError` (because of `raise e` being inside `except AlsoFailsError`). This is misleading because what actually happened is the other way around - we encountered `AlsoFailsError`, and handled it, while trying to recover from `SomeError`. To obtain a traceback that doesn't include `AlsoFailsError`, replace `raise e` with `raise e from None`.

---

In Python 2 you'd store the exception type, value, and traceback in local variables and use the [three-argument form of `raise`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement):

```
try:
    something()
except SomeError:
    t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
    try:
        plan_B()
    except AlsoFailsError:
        raise t, v, tb
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I just also found [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200711/rethrowing_exceptions_in_python.html), thanks! Though there the suggestion is `raise self.exc_info[1], None, self.exc_info[2]` after `self.exc_info = sys.exc_info()` - putting `[1]` to first position for some reason

Comment: @TobiasKienzler `raise t, None, tb` will lose the value of the exception and will force `raise` to re-instantiate it from the type, giving you a less specific (or simply incorrect) exception value. For example, if the raised exception is `KeyError("some-key")`, it will just re-raise `KeyError()` and omit the exact missing key from the traceback.

Comment: So your solution is better. In fact that other post seems to call `raise v, None, tb`, which should probably fail due to the exception's class missing. Hm, [sys.exc_info()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) has a pretty red warning about assigning the traceback value to a local variable, does this require being taken care of in this case? **edit** Ah, there's a box below stating that starting from 2.2 that's handled automatically though it should still be avoided when possible

Comment: I hacked up [another solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18189174/321973) that doesn't require `sys`, but it looks less pythonic to me, so I accept your answer nonetheless

Comment: Ah, note that as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760267/re-raise-python-exception-and-preserve-stack-trace#comment24566185_8760670), this won't work in Python 3 due to a different [raise syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler It should still possible to express that in Python 3 as `raise v.with_traceback(tb)`. (Your comment even says as much, except it proposes to re-instantiate the value.)

Comment: Also, the red warning not to store `sys.exc_info()` in a local variable made sense prior to Python 2.0 (released 13 years ago), but borders on ridiculous today. Modern Python would be near-useless without the cycle collector, as every non-trivial Python library creates cycles without pause and depends on their correct cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, then that warning shouldn't be so prominent in 2.7's docs... Re the Python 3 issue, I misread the `sys.exc_info()` doc thinking the second return value were not the exception instance but the parameters passed to its `__init__` [m-/](http://picardfacepalm.com/)

Comment: get a `TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType` for ` raise t, v, tb`

Comment: @HackToHell Does that happen every time, or only occasionally? Can you print `sys.exc_info()`? Is there additional code between `except SomeError` and `t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()` lines?

Comment: @user4815162342 I found your comment WRT Python 3 (`raise v.with_traceback(tb)`) very useful. Would you consider adding it to your answer?

Comment: With Python3.5 the whole dance is not necessary anyway because the traceback is already stored in the exception. Thus `except SomeError as v:` and `raise v` is sufficient.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs You're right, I've now removed `.with_traceback(tb)` and the call to `sys.exc_info()`. Unfortunately Python 3 specifies *both* tracebacks with the "during handling of the above exception, another exception occurred" message, which is likely not wanted here. The amended answer includes the workaround for that as well.

Comment: @user4815162342 You can kill the "another error occurred" nested error by writing "raise e from None".

Comment: `t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
raise t(v).with_traceback(tb)
` it works for python2/3 both

Answer (score 30):

Even if the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18188660/1513933) is right, it's good to point to the [Six](https://pypi.org/project/six/) library which has a Python 2+3 solution, using [`six.reraise`](https://six.readthedocs.io/index.html#six.reraise).

> six.**reraise**(*exc_type*, *exc_value*, *exc_traceback*=None)
>
> Reraise an exception, possibly with a different traceback.
> [...]

So, you can write:

```
import six


try:
    something()
except SomeError:
    t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
    try:
        plan_B()
    except AlsoFailsError:
        six.reraise(t, v, tb)
```

Comment: Good point - speaking of Six you can also use [`six.raise_from`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.raise_from) if you want to include information that `plan_B()` also failed.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: I think it's a different usage: with `six.raise_from` you create a new exception which is linked to a previous one, you don't **re-raise**, so the trace back is different.

Comment: My point exactly - if you `reraise` you get the impression only `something()` threw `SomeError`, if you `raise_from` you also know that this caused `plan_B()` to be executed but throwing the `AlsoFailsError`. So it depends on the usecase. I think `raise_from` will make debugging easier

Answer (score 21):

As per [Drew McGowen's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188563/how-to-re-raise-an-exception-in-nested-try-except-blocks#comment26652274_18188563), but taking care of a general case (where a return value `s` is present), here's an alternative to [user4815162342's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18188660/321973):

```
try:
    s = something()
except SomeError as e:
    def wrapped_plan_B():
        try:
            return False, plan_B()
        except:
            return True, None
    failed, s = wrapped_plan_B()
    if failed:
        raise
```

Comment: The nice thing about this approach is that it works unchanged in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @user4815162342 Good point :) Though meanwhile in Python3 I'd consider `raise from`, so the stack trace would also let me se plan B failed. Which [can be emulated in Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29833994/321973) by the way.

Comment: you pass some error as 'e' but then dont use it?  Also this doesn't reraise the the specific exception.

Comment: @openCivilisation `as e` could be omitted, it's just a snippet that could be used in a more general way. But what do you mean be "specific exception"? `raise` alone re-raises the exception from `something()` currently handled in the `except` scope, which was the intention

Comment: FYI, a bare `raise` “[re-raises the exception that is currently being handled](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement)” by try-except.

Answer (score 10):

Python 3.5+ attaches the traceback information to the error anyway, so it's no longer necessary to save it separately.

```
>>> def f():
...   try:
...     raise SyntaxError
...   except Exception as e:
...     err = e
...     try:
...       raise AttributeError
...     except Exception as e1:
...       raise err from None
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
SyntaxError: None
>>>
```

Comment: The question is about _another_ exception happening during the `except`. But you're right, when I replace `err = e` by, say, `raise AttributeError`, you get first the `SyntaxError` stack trace, followed by a `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:` and the `AttributeError` stack trace. Good to know, though unfortunately one cannot rely on 3.5+ being installed. PS: ff verstehen nicht-Deutsche vermutlich nicht ;)

Comment: OK, so I changed the example to raise another exception, which (as the original question asked for) gets ignored when I re-raise the first one.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler 3.5+ (which I changed it to) seems to be a globally recognized format. Was denkst du? ;)

Comment: @linusg Agreed :)