# Python: How to store exception value?

Tags: python, exception

How might I store the value of an exception as a variable? Looking at older posts, such as the one below, these methods do not work in Python3. What should I do without using a pip install package?

My goal is to iterate through data, checking it all for various things, and retain all the errors to put into a spreadsheet.

Older post: [Python: catch any exception and put it in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405917/python-catch-any-exception-and-put-it-in-a-variable)

MWE:

```
import sys

# one way to do this
test_val = 'stringing'
try:
    assert isinstance(test_val, int), '{} is not the right dtype'.format(test_val)
except AssertionError:
    the_type, the_value, the_traceback = sys.exc_info()
```

Comment: you mean like `except AssertionError as err:` then unpacking `err`?

Comment: Excepting `AssertionError` seems unnecessary (since you know ahead of time under what conditions it will be raised).

Comment: Thanks, this is quite nice: `except AssertionError as err:`

Answer (score 2):

`except AssertionError as err:`

For more details like unpacking the contents of the exception, see towards the bottom of this block of the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), the paragraph that begins "The except clause may specify a variable after the exception name."

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test whether a certain variable is of type `int`, you can use `isinstance(obj, int)` as you already do.

However you should *never* use `assert` to validate any data, since these checks will be turned off when Python is invoked with the [`-O` command line option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-o). `assert` statements serve to validate your program's *logic*, i.e. to verify certain states that you can *logically* deduce your program should be in.

If you want to save whether your data conforms to some criteria, just store the `True` or `False` result directly, rather than asserting it and then excepting the error (beyond the reasons above, that's unnecessary extra work).

Comment: This is interesting -- `However you should never use assert to validate any data` -- could you please elaborate on how this might look in code?

Comment: @JohnStud What exactly do you mean? Without more context, it's difficult to give a concrete example.

Comment: I want to validate data and you are strongly recommending to not use assertion to validate data, but instead store True/False results. What are you envisioning to yield those True/False results. In other words, what might I do differently, in code? Something like: `result1 = isinstance(test_val, int)`  # yields True or False

Comment: @JohnStud Well, I mean `try: assert X` and then `except AssertionError` means the only way you can arrive in the `except` block is that the previous `assert` statement raised which in turn it only did if `X` was `False`. Hence you get the same information by just looking at `X`. In your case this would be `isinstance(test_val, int)`. The `AssertionError` gives you no information beyond what you already have.