# Try Except in python for "FileNotFound" doesn't stop the execution after the error

Tags: python, try-catch

I am new to "Try & Except" so sorry if my question is very novice. I tried to search the reason but didn't find any.

I am trying a very simple Try an Except for read_csv:

```
try:
  cntrl = pd.read_csv(my_directory + file, sep='|')
except FileNotFoundError:
  logger.critical("file not found")

logger.info(f"file imported. Number of records: {len(cntrl )}")
```

So, when I don't have the file, the **try and except** just prints the error and moves to next line of "logger.info" code to give the below error.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cntrl' referenced before assignment
```

Shouldn't the code stop when error is found and not move to next? When I run the read_csv code without **try and except**, it stops and throws the error as FileNotFound.

Comment: Put your `logger.info` into `else`. Quote from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions): *"The [`try`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) … [`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#except) statement has an optional `else` clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses."*

Comment: The entire concept of doing `try` and `except` is *NOT* to cause the program to crash when there is an error. After the `except` part, it continues.

Comment: in `except` you should `exit()` program to stop rest of code OR you should create empty `cntrl = pd.DataFrame()` to run rest of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some code that should run only if what's in the `try` statement doesn't raise an `except` state with `else`:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Besides that, if you want your code to stop if an error is raised, use `sys.exit()` inside the `except` statement:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html
- [How do I stop a program when an exception is raised in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438894/how-do-i-stop-a-program-when-an-exception-is-raised-in-python)

However, as Aryerez stated, usually the point of the try-except statement is to prevent the code from crashing. If you want it to stop running if an error happens, you can just remove the try-catch statements altogether.